# Click Image Slider and Go to Another Activity in Android Studio

Tags: java, android

1. I'm beginner in Android Studio and I want the images to be clickable so I can jump to another activity where you can find the information about the images you clicked. How can I make this? Any solution?
2. I'm thinking of using the onClickAttribute but I have no idea how to do this.

> here's the activity_main.xml

```
<androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
    android:id="@+id/viewPagerImageSlider"
    android:layout_width="415dp"
    android:layout_height="413dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="150dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="168dp"
    android:paddingStart="80dp"
    android:paddingEnd="80dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

> here's the MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private ViewPager2 viewPager2;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    viewPager2 = findViewById(R.id.viewPagerImageSlider);

    List<SliderItem> sliderItems = new ArrayList<>();
    sliderItems.add(new SliderItem(R.drawable.image1));
    sliderItems.add(new SliderItem(R.drawable.image2));
    sliderItems.add(new SliderItem(R.drawable.image3));
    sliderItems.add(new SliderItem(R.drawable.image4));
    sliderItems.add(new SliderItem(R.drawable.image5));

    viewPager2.setAdapter(new SliderAdapter(sliderItems, viewPager2));

    viewPager2.setClipToPadding(false);
    viewPager2.setClipChildren(false);
    viewPager2.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);
    viewPager2.getChildAt(0).setOverScrollMode(RecyclerView.OVER_SCROLL_NEVER);

    CompositePageTransformer compositePageTransformer = new CompositePageTransformer();
    compositePageTransformer.addTransformer(new MarginPageTransformer(40));
    compositePageTransformer.addTransformer(new ViewPager2.PageTransformer() {
        @Override
        public void transformPage(@NonNull View page, float position) {
            float r = 1 - Math.abs(position);
            page.setScaleY(0.85f + r * 0.15f);
        }
    });

    viewPager2.setPageTransformer(compositePageTransformer);
}

}
```

> here's the SliderItem.java

```
public class SliderItem {
private int image;

SliderItem(int image) {
    this.image = image;
}

public int getImage() {
    return image;
}

}
```

> here's the SliderAdapter.java

```
public class SliderAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SliderAdapter.SliderViewHolder> {

private List<SliderItem> sliderItems;
private ViewPager2 viewPager2;

SliderAdapter(List<SliderItem> sliderItems, ViewPager2 viewPager2) {
    this.sliderItems = sliderItems;
    this.viewPager2 = viewPager2;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public SliderViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    return new SliderViewHolder(
            LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(
                    R.layout.slide_item_container,
                    parent,
                    false
            )
    );
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull SliderViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.setImage(sliderItems.get(position));
    if(position == sliderItems.size() - 2) {
        viewPager2.post(runnable);
    }
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return sliderItems.size();
}

class SliderViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private RoundedImageView imageView;

    SliderViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageSlide);
    }

    void setImage(SliderItem sliderItem) {
        imageView.setImageResource(sliderItem.getImage());
    }
}

private Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        sliderItems.addAll(sliderItems);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
};
}
```

> here's the slide_item_container.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.makeramen.roundedimageview.RoundedImageView 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/imageSlide"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    app:riv_corner_radius="12dp">


</com.makeramen.roundedimageview.RoundedImageView>
```

Comment: Do you want to show the same image on the next activity?

Comment: What information do you want to pass?

Comment: Yes, something like that. If you click the image then it'll take you to the new Activity where the information of that image (place name, location, description) is stored.

Comment: It would be good if you create a temp. cache of that image & pass that uri via Intent to other activity, do not try to send a complete bitmap, else there’s a chance of OOM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will try to explain how to pass data by passing image position from MainActivity to detailedActivity.

I use the following way: First, make an interface with a method name `onPictureClicked()` then implement that interface in your MainActivity to override `onPictureClicked()`. Call this method in your adapter. like: `interface.onPictureClicked(int picturePositon)`

**Interface.java**

```
  public interface ClickedListener {
    
        void onPictureClicked(int position);
     
    }
```

SliderAdapter.java

```
public class SliderAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SliderAdapter.SliderViewHolder> {

private List<SliderItem> sliderItems;
private ViewPager2 viewPager2;
private ClickedListener clickedListener;

SliderAdapter(List<SliderItem> sliderItems, ViewPager2 viewPager2, ClickedListener clickedListener) {
    this.sliderItems = sliderItems;
    this.viewPager2 = viewPager2;
    this.clickedListener = clickedListener;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public SliderViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    return new SliderViewHolder(
            LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(
                    R.layout.slide_item_container,
                    parent,
                    false
            )
    );
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull SliderViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.setImage(sliderItems.get(position));
    if(position == sliderItems.size() - 2) {
        viewPager2.post(runnable);
    }
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return sliderItems.size();
}

class SliderViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private RoundedImageView imageView;

    SliderViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageSlide);
    }

    void setImage(SliderItem sliderItem) {
        imageView.setImageResource(sliderItem.getImage());
        imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    clickedListener.onPictureClicked(getAdapterPosition);
                }
            });
    }
}

private Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        sliderItems.addAll(sliderItems);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
};
}
```

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ClickedListener{

private ViewPager2 viewPager2;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    viewPager2 = findViewById(R.id.viewPagerImageSlider);

    List<SliderItem> sliderItems = new ArrayList<>();
    sliderItems.add(new SliderItem(R.drawable.image1));
    sliderItems.add(new SliderItem(R.drawable.image2));
    sliderItems.add(new SliderItem(R.drawable.image3));
    sliderItems.add(new SliderItem(R.drawable.image4));
    sliderItems.add(new SliderItem(R.drawable.image5));

    viewPager2.setAdapter(new SliderAdapter(sliderItems, viewPager2, this));

    viewPager2.setClipToPadding(false);
    viewPager2.setClipChildren(false);
    viewPager2.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);
    viewPager2.getChildAt(0).setOverScrollMode(RecyclerView.OVER_SCROLL_NEVER);

    CompositePageTransformer compositePageTransformer = new CompositePageTransformer();
    compositePageTransformer.addTransformer(new MarginPageTransformer(40));
    compositePageTransformer.addTransformer(new ViewPager2.PageTransformer() {
        @Override
        public void transformPage(@NonNull View page, float position) {
            float r = 1 - Math.abs(position);
            page.setScaleY(0.85f + r * 0.15f);
        }
    });

    viewPager2.setPageTransformer(compositePageTransformer);
}

  //on image clicked this method will be triggered.
 @Override
    public void onPictureClicked(int position) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DetaildActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("key",position);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

creating this `detailedActivity` to get intent from `MainActivity`

```
public class MainActivity1 extends AppCompatActivity {

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.mainpage);
       //the image position will be passed from the mainActivity to this DetailedActivity
        int getPosition = getIntent().getIntExtra("key", -1);
    }




}
```

This was just a demo through the interface that how you can implement the onClick in adapter to transfer or start another activity.

Comment: Thank you very much, this one works but my problem is this only takes me to a single Activity. What if I want that every image clicked it'll opens up activity for a specific image? Should I make different Activity then copy the code and tweak it a little bit?

Comment: If my answer helped in solving your problem please click on the tick button to accept my answer.

Comment: I don't if its the right way to do but you can create a new activity with `imageView` only and then pass the clicked image to that activity

Comment: Okay it works, thank you for the help. I'll try to find way to solve the other problem.